# how to get started with Grails3 and Google as ID Provider

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, grails3, grails-3.3

I would like to get started with a simple Grails app which allows my users to login through several openIDConnect providers like google.

So I started to add some dependencies to my project:

```
compile 'org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:3.2.0'
compile 'org.grails.plugins:spring-security-oauth2:1.1.0'
compile 'org.grails.plugins:spring-security-oauth2-google:1.1.0'
```

and initialized `spring-security` via

```
grails s2-quickstart com.yourapp User Role
```

and `oauth2` via

```
grails init-oauth2 com.yourapp User OAuthID
```

then I've added

```
static hasMany = [oAuthIDs: OAuthID]
```

to my `User`. In the `application.yaml` I've configured google as auth provider. The google setup seems to be ok - it is take from another project.

As a last step, I've added

```
       <oauth2:connect provider="google" id="google-connect-link">Google</oauth2:connect>
        Logged with google?
        <oauth2:ifLoggedInWith provider="google">yes</oauth2:ifLoggedInWith>
        <oauth2:ifNotLoggedInWith provider="google">no</oauth2:ifNotLoggedInWith>
```

to my `index.gsp` to able to invoke the login and see what is going on.

So far, so good. After successfull login with google, I am redirected to `http://localhost:8080/oauth2/createaccount` where I have to chose if I would like to create a new user or link to an existing one.

If I try to create a new one, it fails with

```
Class
java.lang.NullPointerException
Message
Request processing failed; nested exception is org.grails.gsp.GroovyPagesException: Error processing GroovyPageView: [views/index.gsp:60] Error executing tag <oauth2:ifLoggedInWith>: Cannot invoke method sessionKeyForAccessToken() on null object
Caused by
Cannot invoke method sessionKeyForAccessToken() on null object
```

(btw: you have to use a strong password in order to avoid another error message)

Grails V3.3.1 running on Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

had to figure out that this is a bug in the `grails-spring-security-oauth2`-plugin, but the fix hasn't been published to the Grails central repo:

https://github.com/MatrixCrawler/grails-spring-security-oauth2/issues/9